# differences between branches in fossil

Tags: merge, fossil

In [fossil-scm](http://fossil-scm.org/) I have 2 branches and have cherry picked the commits to apply in  the merge with:

```
fossil merge --cherrypick chg01
```

How can I spot which commits has been merged on branch2 from branch1 ? Actually I need to know **which commits wasn't merged** so that I can merge them if necessary.

In git there's this command that can do that:

```
#view diffs between branches
git log --graph --left-right --cherry-pick --oneline branch1...branch2
```

In the example below, I wish to know  that **rfc-02** was not applied to **testing** branch.

```
# ----------------------------------
# Create the repo and branches
# ----------------------------------

fossil new main.fossil
fossil ui main.fossil &
mkdir developer
cd developer
fossil clone ../main.fossil local.fossil
fossil open local.fossil
fossil branch new testing trunk
fossil branch new production testing
#
# ..[add some files]
#
fossil addremove
fossil ci -m "rfc-01 ticket [12345678]" --tag rfc-01

# ----------------------------------
# Let's merge that change
# ----------------------------------

cd ..
mkdir tests
cd tests
fossil clone ../main.fossil local.fossil
fossil open local.fossil testing
fossil merge --cherrypick rfc-01
#
# ..[add some files]
#
fossil addremove
fossil ci -m "rfc-01 tested [12345678]" --tag rev-01

# ----------------------------------
# Let's do more changes
# ----------------------------------

cd ../developer
fossil update
#
# ..[change/add some files]
#
fossil addremove
fossil ci -m "rfc-02 ticket [22345678]" --tag rfc-02
#
# ..[change/add some more files]
#
fossil addremove
fossil ci -m "rfc-03 ticket [32345678]" --tag rfc-03

# ----------------------------------
# Now merge one change
# ----------------------------------

cd ../tests
fossil update
fossil merge --cherrypick rfc-03
fossil addremove
fossil ci -m "rfc-03 tested [12345678]" --tag rev-03
```